# Align Divs in rows and columns

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align divs in rows and columns. Tried everything to align them in a single row but it didn't work for me.
I tried both `float:left` and `display:inline-block` properties for `.user-rack` but no luck. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/himanshuy/aCGjr/)

Comment: Please always validate your HTML before asking here. A lot of precious time can be saved by doing just that. For example, it would have caught your self-closing divs, that simply do not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check your Inspector?

Using `<div />` is invalid and will only cause nesting.

Comment: Oh! Thanks. I didn't know about it.